# getResource, image width returns -1

Tags: java, image, jar, load

I have the following snippet that loads the images:

```
    String imgName = "/assets/" + name;
    URL imgURL = Groovy.class.getResource(imgName);
            System.out.println(imgURL.getPath());
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image image = tk.getImage(imgURL);
    return image;
```

And where the image is drawn:

```
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        System.out.println(background.getWidth(null));
        if (background.getWidth(null) < 0)
            System.exit(1);
```

However imgURL always returns null. I'm using Eclipse (and fresh to it, blegh), and running the classes with run or debug option. If I change the path, it gives a file not found exception.

File structure is as followed:

Project -> src and assets -> src has Groovy, assets has image -> Groovy has Groovy.class

Edit: I switched back to Netbeans. The imgURL is now loading fine and getPath returns it's correct path. However the image width / height return -1. This is the actual problem now.

Edit: -1 means that the width is not yet known, however displaying the image shows a white screen.

Comment: Can you clarify to a greater degree just where *exactly* are your class files and where *exactly* are the images? Perhaps post an image of these guys in Eclipse's package explorer.

Comment: You changed the IDE, and Java code which didn't work now works? Java is Java, and the IDE has nothing to do with your problem. Post a screenshot of your tree of folders and files, as asked by Hovercraft Full Of Eels.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/screenshotat20120107215.png/

Comment: Being that it is run not from a jar could have though. Switching from Eclipse to Netbeans changed this. I changed the snippet too, as well as the file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resided in the use the toolkit to get the image, possibly because I'm using OpenJDK? Anyway, using ImageIO.read(imgURL) fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to the rescue:

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>   Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
> ```
>        modified_package_name/name
> ```
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted > for '.' ('\u002e').

In short: relative paths can't use `..` to go a level up. Use an absolute name (starting with a `/`, from the root of the classpath).

Moreover, getResource loads resources from the classpath. If the image is not in the classpath, it won't work. Your file tree is not clear at all, but it seems that you haven't understood what the classpath is. If you want to load a file from the file system, use File IO, not resources.